# unchecked call to addItem(E) as a member of the raw type JComboBox Java

Tags: java

Quiero cargar en un `combobox` todos los **DNIs** almacenados en mi base de datos. Lo realiza correctamente pero tengo un problema al compilar mi proyecto y me sale el siguiente **warning**:

```
linea 76: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addItem(E) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
            jComboBox_DNIs.addItem("Seleccione un DNI...");
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
linea 80: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addItem(E) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
                jComboBox_DNIs.addItem(i.next());
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
```

**¿A qué se debe?**

Os muestro el código necesario:

```
        private JComboBox<String> jComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();

        ArrayList<String> dnis = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Cargamos los valores de la función "cargar_dni" de Conexiones.java en el arrayList "dni".
        dnis = Conexiones.cargar_dni();

        if(!dnis.isEmpty()){
            //Creamos un iterator para recorrer el ArrayList.
            Iterator<String> i = dnis.iterator();
            //Dato inicial del jComboBox_DNIs
            jComboBox_DNIs.addItem("Seleccione un DNI...");
            //Recorremos el iterator "i".
            while(i.hasNext()){
                //Añadimos a los items cada dni.
                jComboBox_DNIs.addItem(i.next());
            }

            //Creamos una variable de la clase TextAutoCompleter.
            TextAutoCompleter tac = new TextAutoCompleter(textfield_ciudad);
            //Creamos un arrayList de ciudades y le cargamos las ciudades.
            ArrayList <String> ciudades = Conexiones.cargar_ciudad();
            //Recorremos el arraylist y añadimos al "tac" cada una de las ciudades.
            for(String ciudad: ciudades){
                tac.addItem(ciudad);
            }
        }
```

**cargar_dni():**

```
   public static ArrayList<String> cargar_dni() {
        ArrayList<String> dnis = new ArrayList<String>();
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todos los DNIs de la tabla "clientes".
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_dnis = "SELECT dni FROM clientes ORDER BY dni ASC";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_dnis);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS DNIs: Mostramos todos los DNIs de la tabla 'clientes'.");
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String dni = rs.getString("dni");
                dnis.add(dni);
                i++;
            }
            //System.out.println(dnis);
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Ha habido un error.");
        }
        return dnis;
    }
```

EDITADO: Aquí he añadido el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Omaza, es al objeto jComboBox_DNIs al que tienes que añadirle el tipo de elementos, no crear un nuevo objeto llamado "jComboBox".

Comment: ¿Entonces cómo quedaria?

Comment: Tienes que buscar en tu código la declaración del objeto jComboBox_DNIs... en alguna parte tienes que tener  JComboBox jComboBox_DNIs = new JComboBox(); Búscalo y añádele el tipo de datos.

Comment: @omaza1990 Debes usar generic. Quedaría así: `JComboBox<String> jComboBox_DNIs = new JComboBox<>();`

Comment: Me sigue aparaciendo el error en JComboBox

Comment: No consigo solucionar el asunto de combobox... @MrDave1999

Comment: @omaza1990 ¿Cómo pusiste el código? ¿Qué warning sale ahora? ¿Es el mismo? Edita la pregunta y agrega la línea exacta donde genera la advertencia..

Comment: @MrDave1999 Añadí la imagen de dónde añadí el código y me sale el mismo warning. Puedes ver al inicio de la pregunta las 2 líneas exactas del error.

Comment: @omaza1990 ¿Si eliminaste el default code? Debes fijarte si en el código fuente no está el default code (eso lo debes de eliminar).

Comment: @MrDave1999 Agrego el elemento llamado jComboBox_DNIs mediante el elemento JComboBox de Java Swing. ¿Entonces debo declararlo en el principio del programa? Creo que ni aun así se soluciona mi problema.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108672/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-mrdave1999).